# is there something wrong on my crowd sale code?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

trying to deploy crowdsale on  Test-net 
follow the step on https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale#how-to-use 
use an account to transfer ether to the [Crowdsale] 
but jsut no value on balanceOf of [Crowdsale]  , and balanceOf of [MyToken] 
seems nothing works ^^" 
can help me to debug.... 
source code on : https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/s/48C849848BB245F18905C8F499C65DD6Y

PS:
there is a warning , when transfer ether to the [Crowdsale] ,
like this :[Issue won't allow this transaction (Smart contract)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/issue-wont-allow-this-transaction-smart-contract) , but i had add more and more gas to do ether transfer...not works..

--update 20170512--
find one solution, to Fixed [MyToken] , then the buy record / token was successfully created in [Crowdsale] and [MyToken] .

please reference : [Unable to contribute to crowdsale contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8383/unable-to-contribute-to-crowdsale-contract) 

just need to add variable "owner" , to replace "msg.sender" and operate [MyToken] constructor() / transfer().... that's works!!

----------MyToken----------

```
/**/
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    address public owner; //--by hippo

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    //add response ,from event--by hippo
    event ShowCurrentTokenOfOwner(address ownerAddr,uint256 value);
    event ShowCurrentTokenOfTransferAccount(address ownerAddr,uint256 value);
    event ShowLogstr(uint256 str);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) { 
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address
        if (balanceOf[owner] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough --by hippo
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[owner] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender --by hippo
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(owner, _to, _value);                        //--by hippo  

        //--by hippo
        ShowLogstr(_value);
        ShowCurrentTokenOfOwner(owner,balanceOf[owner]);
        ShowCurrentTokenOfTransferAccount(_to,balanceOf[_to]);
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then comunicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }        

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                           // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                             // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* useless mark it
    function burn() payable returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burnFrom() payable returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
    */


}
```

----------Association----------

```
/* The token is used as a voting shares */
contract token { mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;  }


/* define 'owned' */
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    /* what is modifier : http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#modifiers */
    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract tokenRecipient { 
    event receivedEther(address sender, uint amount);
    event receivedTokens(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);

    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData){
        Token t = Token(_token);
        if (!t.transferFrom(_from, this, _value)) throw;
        receivedTokens(_from, _value, _token, _extraData);
    }

    function () payable {
        receivedEther(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}

contract Token {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
}

/* The democracy contract itself */
contract Association is owned, tokenRecipient {

    /* Contract Variables and events */
    uint public minimumQuorum;
    uint public debatingPeriodInMinutes;
    Proposal[] public proposals;
    uint public numProposals;
    token public sharesTokenAddress;

    event ProposalAdded(uint proposalID, address recipient, uint amount, string description);
    event Voted(uint proposalID, bool position, address voter);
    event ProposalTallied(uint proposalID, uint result, uint quorum, bool active);
    event ChangeOfRules(uint minimumQuorum, uint debatingPeriodInMinutes, address sharesTokenAddress);

    struct Proposal {
        address recipient;
        uint amount;
        string description;
        uint votingDeadline;
        bool executed;
        bool proposalPassed;
        uint numberOfVotes;
        bytes32 proposalHash;
        Vote[] votes;
        mapping (address => bool) voted;
    }

    struct Vote {
        bool inSupport;
        address voter;
    }

    /* modifier that allows only shareholders to vote and create new proposals */
    modifier onlyShareholders {
        if (sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender) == 0) throw;
        _;
    }

    /* First time setup */
    function Association(token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesToPassAVote, uint minutesForDebate) payable {
        changeVotingRules(sharesAddress, minimumSharesToPassAVote, minutesForDebate);
    }

    /*change rules*/
    function changeVotingRules(token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesToPassAVote, uint minutesForDebate) onlyOwner {
        sharesTokenAddress = token(sharesAddress);
        if (minimumSharesToPassAVote == 0 ) minimumSharesToPassAVote = 1;
        minimumQuorum = minimumSharesToPassAVote;
        debatingPeriodInMinutes = minutesForDebate;
        ChangeOfRules(minimumQuorum, debatingPeriodInMinutes, sharesTokenAddress);
    }

    /* Function to create a new proposal */
    function newProposal(
        address beneficiary,
        uint etherAmount,
        string JobDescription,
        bytes transactionBytecode
    )
        onlyShareholders
        returns (uint proposalID)
    {
        proposalID = proposals.length++;
        Proposal p = proposals[proposalID];
        p.recipient = beneficiary;
        p.amount = etherAmount;
        p.description = JobDescription;
        p.proposalHash = sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
        p.votingDeadline = now + debatingPeriodInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        p.executed = false;
        p.proposalPassed = false;
        p.numberOfVotes = 0;
        ProposalAdded(proposalID, beneficiary, etherAmount, JobDescription);
        numProposals = proposalID+1;

        return proposalID;
    }

    /* function to check if a proposal code matches */
    function checkProposalCode(
        uint proposalNumber,
        address beneficiary,
        uint etherAmount,
        bytes transactionBytecode
    )
        constant
        returns (bool codeChecksOut)
    {
        Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
        return p.proposalHash == sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
    }

    /* */
    function vote(uint proposalNumber, bool supportsProposal)
        onlyShareholders
        returns (uint voteID)
    {
        Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
        if (p.voted[msg.sender] == true) throw;

        voteID = p.votes.length++;
        p.votes[voteID] = Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender});
        p.voted[msg.sender] = true;
        p.numberOfVotes = voteID +1;
        Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender); 
        return voteID;
    }

    function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) {
        Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
        /* Check if the proposal can be executed */
        if (now < p.votingDeadline  /* has the voting deadline arrived? */
            ||  p.executed        /* has it been already executed? */
            ||  p.proposalHash != sha3(p.recipient, p.amount, transactionBytecode)) /* Does the transaction code match the proposal? */
            throw;

        /* tally the votes */
        uint quorum = 0;
        uint yea = 0;
        uint nay = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
            Vote v = p.votes[i];
            uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter);
            quorum += voteWeight;
            if (v.inSupport) {
                yea += voteWeight;
            } else {
                nay += voteWeight;
            }
        }

        /* execute result */
        if (quorum <= minimumQuorum) {
            /* Not enough significant voters */
            throw;
        } else if (yea > nay ) {
            /* has quorum and was approved */
            p.executed = true;
            if (!p.recipient.call.value(p.amount * 1 ether)(transactionBytecode)) {
                throw;
            }
            p.proposalPassed = true;
        } else {
            p.proposalPassed = false;
        }
        // Fire Events
        ProposalTallied(proposalNumber, yea - nay, quorum, p.proposalPassed);
    }
}
```

----------Crowdsale----------

```
/**/
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal; uint public amountRaised; uint public deadline; uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool public fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool public crowdsaleClosed = false;
    address public creator;

    /* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
        creator = msg.sender;
    }

    /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () payable {
        if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
        uint amount = msg.value;  
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }
        /**/
        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }

    }

    function beneficiarySafeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if(creator!=msg.sender) throw;
        if (fundingGoalReached) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the source code in the question in case the link gets removed. Also, you can answer your own question, and accept that answer if that solves your issue.

Comment: try to past my code, but cannot show well, it's hard to read.... so,if someone need to view code , please mail me : itman8ks@gmail.com ~

Comment: You can also format your code. Just select the code piece and press Ctrl+K.